# Which of the following two IUPAC names would be accurate according to 1993 IUPAC rules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I'm not looking for answers that are based on 2013 IUPAC recomendation based rules. But rather the old 1993 rules of IUPAC.

The two names are :
1.) Penta-1,2-dien-5-ol
2.) Penta-3,4-dien-1-ol

would we start numbering from the carbon attached to the main functional group [i.e.,secondary suffix] which would give us locants at 1,3 and 4 or just simply follow the lowest locant rule giving us locants 1,2 and 5 ?

Again, I'm specifically looking for name that be accurate on basis of 1993 IUPAC rules and not the PIN.

What rules to keep in mind while naming this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning numbering of locants according to the recommendations of [1979](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_869.htm), [1993](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_317.htm), as well as 2013, the lowest locant is given first to the principal group that is named as suffix (here: -ol) and then to unsaturation (ene/yne).

Thus, the correct name according to the 1993 and 2013 recommendations is **penta-3,4-dien-1-ol.** (The 1979 recommendations had a different placement of locants in the name.)

See also this example given in the 1993 recommendations: [pent-4-en-2-ol](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_337.htm)